# is it possible to determine installed packages on a secondary mounted drive?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, dpkg

I'm "upgrading" to a new distro (from Linux Mint 15 -> 16) by performing a fresh installation to a new drive, and referencing my original drive as needed.

I've currently booted to my new installation (Linux Mint 16), and I've mounted my original drive (Linux Mint 15), so I can access all the raw data just fine. It'd be convenient if I could see the packages that I had installed previously without the (admittedly minor) hassle of swapping my cables and rebooting back and forth.

Basically I'm looking for an alternative to `dpkg --get-selections` (or `apt` equivalents, etc) that I can use on a non-running drive, such as a raw file location where this info may be stored. *(Edit: By "non-running" I mean that it is attached and running, but was not booted, and is mounted on `/mnt/old` or some such.)*

Is this a Thing That Can Be Done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume you mean with non-running that it is attached and running, but was not booted, and mounted on `/mnt/old`:

```
dpkg --root=/mnt/old --get-selections
```

should work.

You can also boot the old partitions once and redirect the output of `dpkg --get-selections` to a file ones and read from that.

Comment: Fantastic. Booting to the old partition and snapshotting the output was my backup plan, certainly, but I've got server daemons running and so was reticent to reboot. :-) Also -- I checked `man dpkg` to see how I missed the `--root` option, and found two things: (1) the description implies that `--root` is just an alias for `--instdir` and `--admindir` (2) using both flags separately does NOT succeed, though `--root` does. (When using the individual flags, I get this error: `dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/mnt/old' for reading: No such file or directory`)